# Locale Agnostic Capitalize or Decapitalize with sed y command

Tags: sed

I'm looking for the best (i.e. locale agnostic) way to capitalize or decapitalize a string in `sed`.

I realize this could be accomplished with `tr`. But I want to do de-capitalizing as part of a larger sed script and do it only for certain lines.

And actually, this solution with `tr` appears to ignore accented characters on my machine!

```
<commands> | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

I know that the y command of `sed` can be used to replace occurrences of one set of characters with characters from another set. And this can be used to capitalize or uncapitalize a string.

However, this would be a naïve approach

```
<commands> | sed 'y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/'
```

Because it doesn't account for accented characters.

Of course, you could just include ALL accented characters on both sides, but it seems like there should be a better way.

I'm aware of equivalence classes like `[=e=]`, which in this case would match all variations of "e". But it doesn't look like I can use that with the y command – at least not the way I want to:

```
<commands> | sed 'y/[=a=]bcd[=e=]/[=A=]BCD[=E=]/'
```

Sed doesn't complain about the above, but it doesn't work either.

I also tried this, with the same (lack of) results:

```
<commands> | sed 'y/[a-z]/[A-Z]/'
```

Is there a way to do what I want other than listing every single character that could possibly be encountered?

Comment: I don't think "locale agnostic" is possible. For us, capitalized `i` is `I`, but in Turkish it's `İ`. Similarly, decapitalized `I` is `i`, but in Turkish it's `ı`.

Comment: Which `sed` is this about? GNU `sed` might be able to handle some of this but not normal `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

From the GNU [sed documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Less-Frequently_002dUsed-Commands), the y command requires that the length of the source characters exactly match that of the destination characters. Neither the left nor the right side is treated as a regex.

Executing the following

```
echo 'forté' | sed 'y/[[:lower:]]/[[:upper:]]/'
```

Gives

```
fprté
```

As you can see, the source characters were treated as just a jumble of characters, not a regex.

So it would seem that listing out all the characters you could possibly encounter is the only option for the y command.

But there's another way using the "s" command if you're using GNU sed!

```
echo 'forté' | sed 's/[[:lower:]]/\u&/g'
echo 'FORTÉ' | sed 's/[[:upper:]]/\l&/g'
```

`[[:lower:]]` and `[[:upper:]]` match any/all characters that need to be changed. `\u` and `\l` make the change. And `g` ensures this happens for every occurrence in the line.